# How to install postgresql-contrib-11 on CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, postgresql

So, I was trying to install extension `citext` on PostrgeSQL 11.1, but of course I've encountered an error:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-11/share/extension/citext.control": No such file or directory
```

I ran `sudo yum install postgresql-contrib` , but dependency for version 9.2 was installed.
So where to find and how to install citext on PostgreSQL 11.1 on CentOS 7.6 ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you have the correct rpm files installed for postgres 11. Then run

`sudo yum install postgresql11-contrib`

Here is a good article for installing postgresql on centos7

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-postgresql-on-centos-7/

Comment: Also potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025515/how-do-i-import-modules-or-install-extensions-in-postgresql-9-1